# How to automate git commit without calling the "-m" option, to handle inner quotes?

Tags: c++, git

Here is my problem. I have a C++ script which takes strings as messages which will be used for the commit messages.

This works for almost all cases, however the problem arises when `<msg>` contains either escaped single quotes or double quotes, so the command looks like:

```
git commit -m 'A new message \' with many escaped \" \' quotes \"'
```

And so git will get confused.

I don't want to think of how to escape these quotes within the commit message so I think the best way is to avoid using the `-m` flag, **that is to just do a plain `git commit` and pass `<msg>` to vi or ed somehow, then quit and save**.

**My attempt using ed:**

```
git commit | ed << <msg>
```

**vi**:

```
git commit | vi << I << <msg> << :wq
```

As you can see I am really new to linux and I haven't found anything on the web to describe what I am trying to do. **So the question again is: what is the correct sequence of shell commands to commit to git a specific message without invoking the `-m` flag**. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don’t open a shell; spawn git directly and pass `["commit", "-m", message]` as argv.

Comment: Take a look at the `-F` [flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit). Alternatively, `-C` might also work, but since it also keeps the timestamps, you might object to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re just running Git, don’t spawn a shell at all; spawn `git` directly and pass `["git", "commit", "-m", message]` as its argv. In C++:

```
#include <string>

extern "C" {
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
}

struct child_process {
    FILE* file;
    pid_t pid;

    child_process(FILE* file_, pid_t pid_) :
        file(file_),
        pid(pid_) {}
};

template<std::size_t n> static child_process popenv(std::string const& path, std::string const (&args)[n]) {
    char const* const c_path = path.c_str();
    char const* c_argv[n + 2];

    c_argv[0] = c_path;
    c_argv[n + 1] = NULL;

    std::size_t i = 1;

    for (std::string const& arg : args) {
        c_argv[i++] = arg.c_str();
    }

    int fds[2];
    pipe(fds);
    pid_t const pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1) {
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category());
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        dup2(fds[1], 1);
        execvp(c_path, const_cast<char* const*>(c_argv));
        _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return child_process(fdopen(fds[0], "r"), pid);
}

static int pclosev(child_process const& process) {
    int status;

    fclose(process.file);

    if (waitpid(process.pid, &status, 0) == -1) {
        throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category());
    }

    return status;
}
```

```
std::string const message = "A new message ' with many escaped \" ' quotes \"";
child_process p = popenv("git", {"commit", "-m", message});

// read from p.file; use pclosev() instead of pclose()
```

If you really do need a shell for some reason, pass the message in its argv and run `git commit -m "$1"`.

If you really need to have `git commit` read its message from standard input for some reason, run `git commit -F -`. (`-` can be replaced with any file to read that file.)

Comment: how would one spawn git directly? Do you mean use a library like libgit2?

Comment: @Liz: No, still by running the process. How are you doing it right now?

Comment: popen("git commit -m <msg>", "r"))

Comment: I might be getting confused by the wording, but I think I'm doing already what you're saying, by opening a shell I meant I opened a process with the git command like above. It can handle everything except quotes within quotes

Comment: @Liz: Are you using the return value of `popen` to read the output of `git commit`, or just waiting for it to exit?

Comment: First one but thats not the issue. Try commiting a file yourself next time you work with git and have quotes within the quotes of the -m flag, you'll see that git wont let you.

Comment: @Liz: Yes, I understand the problem. I added a code snippet, but have to update it if you’re reading output.